# Is there are SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Web Service that will allow me to access the site collection administrators for a site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

Which web service and which property or method would I use to access the site collection administrators for a site?  Also, is it possible through a webservice to enumerate all of the site collections and get the administrators from each one?

I don't have a proper development environment so I need to do this through the web services.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this functionality exists natively.  You should be able to create your own service hosted in SharePoint though and create the functionality you are looking for.

- Here is a [link](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/03/10/how-deploy-a-wcf-service-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx) on how to host WCF services within SharePoint 2010.
- Enumerating Site Collections should be relatively trivial.
- The SPWeb.SiteAdministrators collection will return a list of all site collection administrators.

Answer (score 1):

As Matt said, there's nothing built in to do this. The most similar thing you can do using only built in functionality, is to browse the user groups and users of the root web:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://foo");
GroupCollection grps = ctx.Web.SiteGroups;
ctx.Load(grps);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Group grp in grps)
{
   // do something with each group
}
```